# How do you open curtains and fade them out in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am currently programming a website for a client. She wants her name to be in the middle of the screen and when a user clicks on her name; she wants her name to open up like a curtain and fade out, while a picture and a menu fade in.

She wants her first name to move left and fades out; and at the same time, her last name moves right and fades out.

Soon after that, a picture with a menu fade in.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "like a curtain." That could mean that the image gets cut down the middle and then the two parts then peel away from the touching bottom corners, but it could also mean that the two parts just slide away from each other. Likewise, it could also mean that the text (her name) gets pulled up from the bottom. This is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty first version using absolute positioning, although I'm sure you can do it using `position: relative`, but just to show the general idea ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vE6Pt/)):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $('span.first').animate({
            left: '-=50'
        });

        $('span.second').animate({
            left: '+=50'
        });

        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
})();​
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <span class="first">Na</span><span class="second">me</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    background-color: red;

}
span { position: absolute; font-size: 20px;  }
span.first { left: 50px }

span.second{ left: 73px }
```

​

Comment: By the way, I left the menu out but something like that goes after the fadeOut() effect I applied to the name.